# Where do we put composer install for docker for Laravel or Lumen

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, lumen

In Attempt #1, the `composer install` doesnt create vendor folders, because the container will mount the volume all over again.

In Attempt #2, the `CMD` will trigger the container to exit with status 0 after finishing the commands.

So, what is the best implementation to run the `composer install && php artisan migrate`?
My expectation is `composer install && php artisan migrate` will be run everytime the container starts.

Attempt #1

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm

COPY . /var/www
WORKDIR /var/www

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev \
    mysql-client libmagickwand-dev zip unzip git curl vim --no-install-recommends \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql gd bcmath \
    && php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" \
    && php composer-setup.php --install-dir /usr/local/bin --filename=composer \
    && php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');" \
    && composer install \
    && php artisan migrate
```

Attempt #2

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm

COPY . /var/www
WORKDIR /var/www

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev \
    mysql-client libmagickwand-dev zip unzip git curl vim --no-install-recommends \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql gd bcmath \
    && php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" \
    && php composer-setup.php --install-dir /usr/local/bin --filename=composer \
    && php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');" 

CMD bash -c "composer install && php artisan migrate"
```

The `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:

  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: app.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    environment:
      - "DB_PORT=3306"
      - "DB_HOST=db"
    tty: true

  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: web.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    ports:
      - 8080:80

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE=homestead"
      - "MYSQL_USER=homestead"
      - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret"
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
    ports:
        - "33061:3306"

volumes:
  dbdata:
```

Comment: What is the point of copying your full directory to container's /var/www if you override all its content with a mount afterwards ?

Comment: Hi @Zeitounator, well I'm still beginner to docker. Could you share how should be the best practice way? Cheers

Comment: Actually, copying files in the `Dockerfile` and then mounting the same folder inside `docker-compose.yml` is a common practice: You want the built final image to contain the application files, but you don't want to have to rebuild the image every time you make a code change during development.

Comment: It might be common practice, but I much better like to use a specific image for dev (with all needed debug and build tools) where I mount the local code during development (without copying it) and later build a much lighter immutable image (using multistage build if needed) that goes to QA and finally reaches production when successfully tested.

Comment: I see, but my focused question is "My expectation is composer install && php artisan migrate will be run everytime the container starts."
How to achieve that?